# Arduino communicate between 2 different router in different location

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, ethernet

I am on my final year project in I.T. my project is that i want to create a helicopter or quadcopter with a camera attached to it. And i want to control the copter via wifi from an android phone in another location. e.g, the copter is at home and i am somewhere else (work, university etc..). so i wanted to know if i can connect both via 2 different routers and control it and get the live video the camera is actually recording (the idea is to monitor your house when you are away). if that is possible, which arduino hardware will enable me to do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the Arduino that has anything to do with this but the routing, port forwarding and/or VPN that you set up between your routers.

I'd have thought, since you're in your final year of IT, you'd at least have some rudimentary knowledge of routing, port forwarding and VPNs...